# Chrome: Flash Video Player doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, flash, google-chrome

could you explain me why my flash video player doesn't work in Chrome while it perfectly works in other browsers ? (Firefox and IE)

You'll see it flickering...

thanks

Comment: +1 to undo a downvote. I thought SO was to help with coding problems... Tho admitally he's not providing source code...

Comment: @Kurru: It's a javascript/html/css issue, the code is on the site he links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [chrome developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) you'll see that something keeps on adding a `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to the object every second. Is there a timer somewhere in your code that should have been stoppend and isn't being stopped on chrome?

Update: it must be the `changeSize()` function that keeps being called. (By `__flash__toXML` as you can see when you start debugging by putting a breakpoint on the `changeSize` function)

Comment: uhm, yeah.. well no, there is not timer. The changeSize() fuction is triggered from the Flex code when the browser send metadata to the Flex app (basically it pass the video path) <mx:VideoDisplay metadataReceived="passSize(); ... /> passSize calls changeSize() to pass back the video size. Probably Chrome keep sending metadata ?

Comment: I've now added a removeEventListener from my video player so that when the changeSize() function is triggered, the listener is removed and the flash player is not anymore invoking ExternalCall.. but still nothing ;(

Comment: I've temporanely fixed by checking if embed exists before to add it. But the changeSize function is called iteratively, so it is not a "clear" solution.